# Where did he hide the key?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, pattern, visual

On his sister's birthday, James gave her a special treasure chest containing her birthday gift. However, knowing her love for riddles and puzzles, he did not give her the key. Instead, he gave her this Sudoku, wished her luck, and left her to solve the mystery. All he told her was that he had hidden the key somewhere inside their house.

[image]

Where did James hide the key?

Comment: Do you mean to have two 1s in the fourth row?

Comment: @JeremyDover No! Thanks for catching that type. I've double checked everything else as well and it is now correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

He hid them in the

> COFFEE POT, the result of interpreting the given numbers as Braille.

Comment: Wow, cool. So the numbers are red herring after all

Comment: the best reply i could make is "Bruh." well done deus!

Comment: Btw, how did you get this? I don't see any hint in the question for the method that you used.

Comment: @justhalf I just knew that Braille was arranged in 2x3 blocks like the ones in the question.